# “Easily find again pages you have been reading”

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

This is from a [website](https://sites.google.com/site/contentsindexprofiles/home/home1/home-2/home-3/home-4/home-5/home-6/home-7/home-8/home-9):

> Recently visited pages
> Easily find again ***pages you have been reading.***

The Present Perfect Continuous is being used here but would it be possible to say: ***"pages you have read"*** without any difference in meaning?

Comment: I thing I think deserves comment here is the phrase "easily find again pages ...". It seems to be a style that's spreading in business-speak. "Easily find pages you have been reading again" would be the normal way of saying it in my world and there's something about the corporate nature of this trend that bugs me.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, *'has/have been....'* is used for the event that has a starting point and **is still** happening. Since the visitor on the website is *still reading the page,* it reads 'pages *you have been* reading...'

I've worked with IT professionals. On websites, we have a *session* which means particular user's activity from coming onto the website till s/he *leaves it.* As the visitor is still on the website and in the *same session,* it is possible to find the pages the *user has been reading.*

Comment: yes, but you can only read one page at a time, so as soon as I leave one page and start reading the next one, I have read the first one.

Comment: that's why they wrote 'pages.'

Comment: Yes, but as soon as you finish a page you have read it = completion = present perfect simple. You are not reading that particular page anymore, so why use the continuous.  Do you understand my confusion?

Comment: @anouk Not true. The continuous is used for recency (ongoing or finished). The present perfect (simple) emphasizes that you've read the pages (acquired state), rather than that you've been reading them (progress, temporary activity).

Comment: I realized I used *finished* rather loosely. However, you obviously finished reading them, i.e., you stopped with it. That doesn't mean you completed them, i.e. read all of it. So maybe add "in-the-middle-of-it" to "in progress" (there's a difference), and "temporary activity".

Comment: @userr2684291 why do you say "obviously"? what is obvious about it? what is the difference between "in progress" and "in-the-middle-of-it"?

Comment: @anouk I said "obviously" because of the context (namely, the site had recently been closed). Don't read too much into it. Regarding your second question: the latter need not be the necessary consequence of the former – *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston et al., 2002) gives this example: *When I said 'the boss' I **was referring** to you*, in which *saying* and *referring* are coterminous.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is contained within your question itself. There is such word as *recently* there. It means that the authors of seemingly some online workbook supposed such phrase as *the pages that you have been reading recently*. Within the same reasoning, the authors of the workbook implied *shorter, temporary actions and situations*.  This adverb *recently* is not used with the Present Perfect tense in this context. That is why the answer to your question is that; no, it would not be possible to say *pages you have read* without any difference in meaning. The phrases are different with their meanings in the context.